# SQL - Count instances in 1 field with variations in 2nd

Tags: sql, countif

Thanks for taking a second to read this... Have tried this in SQL, Python, and VBA with no luck (various reasons).

The data and concept are, I think, pretty simple - but I can't seem to make it work.

Column 1 has a stock market ticker; Column 2 has the company name.  However, many of the company names have been truncated, or have changed over time.  I want to find every instance of each ticker, where that ticker has more than 1 name.

So for example, my file has these 4 lines

```
IBM | Int Bus Mach
IBM | International Business M
IBM | Intl Bus Machines
IBM | Int Bus Mach
```

I would like to see the 3 unique company names

```
IBM | Int Bus Mach
IBM | International Business M
IBM | Intl Bus Machines
```

Any ideas are certainly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to your data examples, you should do something like this:

```
SELECT
    market_ticker,
    company_name,
    count(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    market_ticker,
    company_name
```

The extra column will give how many times the market ticker and company name repeat.

Comment: Thank you!  I think maybe I didn't provide a critical detail.  Each ticker will have an entry for every day that it had sufficient movement to be added to the database.  So I may have 50 entries for 
IBM | Intl Bus Machines

Then another 10 for 
IBM | International Business Machines

I'm just trying to get a list that would have both, distinct names for IBM.

My apologies for leaving that off - I've spent 3 hours in Python today, which has my brain short circuiting!

Comment: add the distinct clause. I think it will do the work: select distinct market_ticker, company_name, count(*)

Comment: @JP_Romano That is what this query would return. If you only want the company names for one market ticker, you can filter it in a `WHERE` statement and remove the market_ticker column. Could you clarify why this isn't doing what you want?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong - but it's not returning the correct counts.... I only checked two entries, but  one was showing double the actual count, and the other was showing 1 when there were more than 5 unique names.  Thank you, though - I sincerely appreciate your time and suggestions

Comment: @JP_Romano . . . This correctly answers the question that you asked.  If you have another question, the proper procedure is to accept this answer and ask another question.  Revising the question is rude, because it can invalidate an answer, drawing downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

2 step Sql Solution here.
I would do the following

Simple distinct query to get all ticker and company combos then pivot

```
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TickerColumn ORDER BY NameColumn) AS NameNum
into #Temp
From 
(
Select distinct TickerColumn, NameColumn
from Table
)x
```

Then Pivot ColumnNames

```
Select TickerColumn, [1],[2],[3],[4]
From
(select * from #temp) as Source
Pivot
(
Max(NameColumn)
For NameNum in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ---You can add or reduce number of columns
) As PivotTable;
```

Comment: Please disregard previous. this will not help you goal

Answer (score 0):

May be try something like this. Would bring distinct names.

```
    WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT market_ticker
        ,Company_name
    FROM Stocks
    )
SELECT a.market_ticker
    ,b.Company_name
FROM cte a
INNER JOIN stocks b
    ON a.market_ticker = b.market_ticker
GROUP BY a.market_ticker
    ,b.company_name
HAVING count(a.company_name) >= 2
ORDER BY 1
    ,2
```

Comment: That looks great, thank you.  But that includes codes that have only 1 unique name... 
Don't go through any more trouble - your help is appreciated, but I think I just have to do it the old fashioned way in VBA.